# Show form in designer with code executed during load

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I have a windows form that I am making in C# using Visual Studio 2013. The form contains a ListView that has 2 columns. The ListView itself is created inside of the InitializeComponent() which is auto-generated by VS. I actually add the column headers outside of InitializeComponent(). The problem is that I want the [Design] view in VS to show the column headers that I declare but I don't want to clutter up the InitializeComponent() method in addition to it also saying that I should not modify the contents of the code within the method.

Basically what I did was create a method that adds the two column headers to the ListView and formats them:

```
private void initRecipListView()
{
    this.recipList.Columns.Add("Recipient", -2, System.Windows.Forms.HorizontalAlignment.Left);
    this.recipList.Columns.Add("Number of Reports", -2, System.Windows.Forms.HorizontalAlignment.Left);
}
```

I want to call this method so that those two columns are added and visible during runtime AS WELL AS when I view the form inside of the VS designer window. I have tried putting that method inside of the constructor for the form itself which works during runtime but doesn't in the designer window.

Any idea where I need to put this method for it to be called and used when I am viewing the form in the designer window?

Comment: Didn't you already ask this?  It really isn't clear why you want to avoid just adding these columns in the designer.  Your argument to avoid cluttering up the InitializeComponent method does not hold water.

Answer (score 1):

You can derive your own class from ListView and implement a scheme like this.  Basic ingredients you need is presetting the number of columns in the constructor and exposing properties to allow you to set the column header text.  Override OnClientSizeChanged() to keep the columns centered and deal with the vertical scroll bar appearing.

Add a new class and paste the code shown below.  Compile.  Drop the new control from the top of the toolbar.  You can set the Column1Name and Column2Name properties in the designer or in your code.  You'll get the WYSIWYG view in the designer.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class MyListView : ListView {
    public MyListView() {
        this.Columns.Add("Unnamed1");
        this.Columns.Add("Unnamed2");
        this.View = View.Details;
    }
    public string Column1Name {
        get { return this.Columns[0].Text; }
        set { this.Columns[0].Text = value; }
    }
    public string Column2Name {
        get { return this.Columns[1].Text; }
        set { this.Columns[1].Text = value; }
    }
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    [Browsable(false)]
    public new ListView.ColumnHeaderCollection Columns {
        get { return base.Columns; }
    }
    protected override void OnClientSizeChanged(EventArgs e) {
        base.Columns[0].Width = this.ClientSize.Width / 2;
        base.Columns[1].Width = this.ClientSize.Width - base.Columns[0].Width;
        base.OnClientSizeChanged(e);
    }
}
```